# Excel average when data set has #value

Tags: excel

I have a spotty data set in an Excel column and want to compute the average. The column is derived from other data and does contain '#value' entries. Those need to be discarded for average and stddev. How is that accomplished?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 1):

Use the [AGGREGATE()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) Funtion:

```
=AGGREGATE(1,6,A1:B100)
```

The `1` is for average, use `7` or `8` for the Standard dev. The `6` tells it to ignore errors.

See link for more info. The AGGREGATE() Function was introduced in 2010.  If your excel is older then this will not work.